# image is loaded to UIImageView in iOS simulator 6.0, but in 5.1 it is not loaded

Tags: objective-c, ios

did anyone encounter this problem?

here's the code in ViewController.m.  I have a UIImageView in the XIB file attached to IBOutlet named "imageView"

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.co.il/images/nav_logo114.png"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    self.imageView = [self.imageView initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
self.imageView = [self.imageView initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
```

do this:

```
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

and don't forget to `@synthesize imageView`